# IIS Express Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage ... until restart

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I have one asp.net application which I debug locally using IIS Express.
I have a setup by which I access it as `http//machine-name:port/appname` (instead of localhost).

This works smoothly until suddenly out of the blue during debugging I get the message:

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

What ever I do, it does not work again until I restart Windows.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Is there a way to fix this without restarting Windows?
I am using Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010, but this also happens in VS 2012.

**EDIT** This issue stopped occurring. which leads me to believe this was Microsoft bug which they fixed in one of their updates

Comment: Once it stops working in IE on your machine, what did it do in another browser such as Chrome?  If those work, then it's likely not IIS Express, and I couldn't tell from your question.

Comment: To really answer this, we'd need to see the HTTP traffic being generated. Can you run Fiddler, capture the requests and responses between the program working and stopping and then include them here? The general "cannot display the page" message contains zero useful information beyond "something went wrong".

Comment: @Michael it happens in all browsers

Comment: @Tragedian next time this happens i will get you the fiddler results

Comment: Was this issue ever resolved?

Comment: it automatically stopped happening after a while..so i am thinking one of the windows update fixed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just taking a stab in the dark, since you aren't getting any responses...  Try deleting (or even just rename) the applicationHost.config under "My Documents\IISExpress\config", then open VS.net and run your project again.  A new IISExpress config file will get generated for you.  I have had mine junked up with something in the past, and starting fresh with a new one fixed whatever it was.

Comment: Note, when I tried this it wanted me to run VS as administrator to fix it! Probably not an issue for most folks, but could be.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue in a perticular scenario.

It was like, `Page_Load` event of 1st page contains code to redirect response to 2nd page and `Page_Load` event of 2nd page contains code to redirect response back to 1st page.

So due to this browser response fell into infinite loop and it shows message: "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage".

So I'll suggest you to check the response redirection logic which may be causing problem.

Comment: This only happens in my environment. Others don't have this issue. We all share the same code. Although they use IIS and i use IIS Express.

Comment: This was the answer for me, Thanks Sanjeev. My master page was redirecting to the login screen if user wasn't logged in. The master page was also included in the login screen, so it kept redirecting to itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with a DI framework like Ninject and you are doing changes on your services dependencies, beware not to generate a circular dependency. When starting up the application you might get this same error.